# when a jQuery selector saved in a variable if element remove how to know removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

in Similar questions, It is said that get length attribute if not 0 mean exist.

But in the past you select element and save in a variable after remove element, if you get length will see length not 0 !!!!

test this in jQuery 1.10.2

```
var x = $("h3:first")
$("h3:first").remove();
x.length
```

Comment: you store the result in `x`, if you re-run the query it should update, depending on your html

Comment: @depperm i know by re-run can, but i don't want re-run. this is the reason of save selector.

Comment: what is the similar question you mentioned? What exactly are you expecting to have happen?

Comment: @depperm in my Prj elements many times in a short time call to update, i save selector to improve performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check for a parent.

```js
var $x = $("h3:first");

console.log($x.parent().length);

$x.remove();

console.log($x.parent().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Here I am</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example if you have just one `h3` then `x` keeps the length but re-running the query returns 0 since it no longer exists.

```js
var x = $("h3:first");
$("h3:first").remove();
console.log(x.length);
console.log($("h3:first").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Here I am</h3>
```